# SQL Server Management Studio Restore Database only restores databases one at a time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014; I am trying to restore a number of databases and encountered some strange behavior.

[image]

As expected, the "Add" button allows me to add several `.bak` files.

Everything proceeds normally. However, when it finishes importing, it shows me a dialog saying "Database '[name]' imported successfully", where [name] is the name of the first `.bak` file I added.

[image]

Indeed, I can confirm looking at the Databases in Object Explorer that it added only the first `.bak` file on the list; none of the other items were restored.

I've seen posts that suggest how to write scripts to do this kind of an import, but I'd prefer to do it from the UI.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior and how to fix it?

Yeah, suppose I could just do them one at a time as a workaround, but that's really time-consuming and error-prone - I'd rather just be able to restore all of them at once.

Comment: Have you tried recovering thru SQL queries? I think ssms GUI part attachs only one DB and it's files at a time.

Comment: Do you want to make multiple restores on one single database or do you want to restore multiple databases? From the SSMS you can only restore one database at a time. Regarding the back up media, you can only chose one to do the restore, not more than one. The .bak file can have the full, differential and all the log backups inside.

Comment: Or Powershell? Using a UI to point and click your way through this is error prone - at best. Automation and operations at scale are exactly the *opposite* goal of a UI.

Comment: You could open a new instance of Sql Management studio.  The advantage of scripting it is you would execute each script in its own SQL window.  This would then let the “jobs” run at the same time with each one in its own spid – “thread”.  You effectively are IO bound on how much backup and restore you can do, this can be a way to try to look at your overall system IO level as the size of the databases and page counts are well known and the times are logged.   Be careful on a production box you may find an IO or network limit during critical production times that has bad consequences.

Comment: @asemprini87 I'm trying to restore multiple databases. Am I out of luck in terms of doing that from the SSMS UI?

Comment: No, you aren't out of luck, you just have to do them one at a time (or with multiple instances of SSMS).

Comment: @SqlSurfer Your comment's extremely helpful as well, it should probably be added as an answer IMHO since it seems like it could be useful for future readers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the defined behaviour. The `Add` button allows you select a backup that uses more than one file. The full process involves selecting a database first and then restoring that. As you mention in your question there is the option of using scripts and you can use the interface to give you the script. All you need to do then is to run the scripts as a batch.

Comment: So basically it'll work if a single database is split over several files, but it won't work if there are several databases split over several files?

Comment: @EJoshuaS The number of files is irrelevant. The wizard is designed to restore ***a*** database.

Answer (score 1):

If you open a New Instance of SQL Management studio you could do more than one at once.  This would be the way to work around the built in GUI limitation if you are doing the restore/backup manually.